# How to use xpath xpression to check if data is present or not in wso2 ESB?

Tags: xpath, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have captured my input id in a property and now i want to validate if the property has data or not. How to do this? I have done something like this:

This is my property that i have set:

```
<property xmlns:cct="http://www.tempuri.org/" name="ID" expression="//cct:ID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

This is my xpath xpression that should validate if property has data or not:

```
count(get-property(ID)[text()])>0
```

But this expression is wrong. How to solve this. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your property to this:

```
<property xmlns:cct="http://www.tempuri.org/" name="ID" expression="//cct:ID/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

then test using

```
boolean(get-property('ID'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like below,

```
count(/property[@name='ID']/text())
```

Note that the correct path (instead of /property/..) depends on your xml. you may also use /*/property/... if not sure about the path.

Comment: But here is a problem.When i pass empty value i.e <ID></ID> from try-it, in the property i get this value: ID = <cc
t:ID xmlns:cct="http://tempuri.org"/>.So whenever i check for value in property, i always get data but i want to check if valid data is present in Property or not?